# No free nbd devices while installing multiple instances on openstack

Tags: linux, python-2.7, openstack, openstack-nova, openstack-neutron

I am already running Cirros OS instance on my openstack and now I am trying to install ubuntu instances on the OpenStack, but when I typed command nova list on my controller, it gave me error message as shown in the screen-print attached.

I checked the var/log/nova/nova-compute.log and it shows that no free nbd device and finally failed with timeout.

Any help in this would be great.

Please find the screen-print  for the logs. [screen1.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vl5PR.png)

Comment: OpenStack is unable to create a network connection for your new instance. It either failed to resolve the hostname `openstack-compute` or it failed to connect to a failed `openvswitch` db or both. Try restarting `openvswitch` with `systemctl restart openvswitch.service` or `service openvswitch restart`. Check to make sure that the host `openstack-compute` is resolvable.

Answer (score 1):

This is the real error logs: Unexpected error while running command.
Command: sudo nova-rootwrap /etc/nova/rootwrap.conf ovs-vsctl

Logs:

ERROR nova.network.linux_net [-] Unable to execute ['ovs-vsctl', '--timeout=120', '--', '--if-exists', 'del-port', u'qvo474102f0-19', '--', 'add-port', 'br-int', u'qvo474102f0-19', '--', 'set', 'Interface', u'qvo474102f0-19', u'external-ids:iface-id=474102f0-192c-42ae-a7d0-0de30021f07c', 'external-ids:iface-status=active', u'external-ids:attached-mac=fa:16:3e:4e:bb:8e', 'external-ids:vm-uuid=19ef2bf4-7370-48c9-a3e4-111f6921188d']. Exception: Unexpected error while running command.
Command: sudo nova-rootwrap /etc/nova/rootwrap.conf ovs-vsctl --timeout=120 -- --if-exists del-port qvo474102f0-19 -- add-port br-int qvo474102f0-19 -- set Interface qvo474102f0-19 external-ids:iface-id=474102f0-192c-42ae-a7d0-0de30021f07c external-ids:iface-status=active external-ids:attached-mac=fa:16:3e:4e:bb:8e external-ids:vm-uuid=19ef2bf4-7370-48c9-a3e4-111f6921188d
Exit code: 1
Stdout: u''
Stderr: u'sudo: unable to resolve host openstack-compute\n2016-07-08T21:25:51Z|00002|reconnect|WARN|unix:/var/run/openvswitch/db.sock: connection attempt failed (Protocol error)\novs-vsctl: unix:/var/run/openvswitch/db.sock: database connection failed (Protocol error)\n'

Comment: I'm glad you found the answer to your question. +1

Comment: But I am not sure how to resolve this issue. Any insight in this.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with ovs (openvswitch), just restart the openvswitch on the neutron and compute node of openstack and try again to run the instance, the issue get solved.

Check the ovs status after restarting the services

Check the neutron agent-list status on the controller node and everything should be up.